# PHP - Check Textbox1's value with Button and Shows it in Text box 2

Tags: php, sql

I have created page for inserting employee's attendance.

I just input the Employee Code, and by clicking "**Check**" Button, Employee Name will automatically showing.

But, I've got problem while run the page. The button didn't show the employee name when i click Check Button after filling the employee code.

What's wrong in my code ?

**form_empl.php**

```
<html>
<body>    
Employee Code : <input type="number" name="empl_kode"  placeholder="Employee Code" required="required"><br>

    <button type="button" name="cek_empl" value="cek_empl">Check</button><br>

Employee Name :<input type="text" name="empl_name" value="<?php $data->EMPL_NAME?>"placeholder="Employee Name"><br>

</body>
</html>

<?php
require('empl_function.php');
$empl_kode=$_POST['empl_kode'];
$empl_name=$_POST['empl_name'];
if (isset($_POST['cek_empl'])){
    $Emp=new Employee();
    $show=$Emp->showEmployee();
    while ($data=  ibase_fetch_object($show)){
}
}
?>
```

**empl_function.php**

```
function showEmployee(){
    $sql="SELECT empl_kode,empl_name FROM employee";
    $query=ibase_query($sql);
    return $query;
    }
```

[image: New Attendance Page]

Comment: Do you have javascript that sends a request when the button is pressed? Sounding like a client side vs. server side question..

Comment: @chris85: is it really need javascript to run the page ? can i make it with pure php syntax ?

Comment: For the value, you have to echo the variable for it to show in the front end.

Comment: No, PHP is on the server. Javascript is on the browser. Nothing executed on the client goes to the server unless told to,

Comment: It looks like you need Ajax to run the request if you do not want the user to leave that Web page.

Comment: YOu read about AJAX first. What you want can be achieved through AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: all : thanks for your advice. i'm newbie in web programming world.
now i know that i have to use ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i can run my page with pure PHP. Here it is the code :

**Function for calling the query :**

```
function checkEmplcode($empl_kode){
    $sql="SELECT empl_kode, empl_name FROM employee where empl_kode='$empl_kode'";
    $query=ibase_query($sql);
    $object_empl=ibase_fetch_object($query);
    return $object_empl;
    }
```

In **form_empl.php**, i add this syntax above the form input:

```
if(isset($_POST['cek_empl'])){
           if(isset($_POST['empl_kode']) && !empty($_POST['empl_kode'])){
               $_POST['empl_name'];
           } else {
               echo "Syntax is not right! Please check again !";
           }

            $empl_kode=$_POST['empl_kode'];
            $empl_name=$_POST['empl_name'];

        $Att=new Attendance();
        $object_empl=$Att->checkEmplcode($empl_kode);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any form. So the $_POST[‘’]; will create error.

rewrite it like this

```
<?php
session_start();
$name1xs =$_SESSION['name1xs’];
?>
.
.
.

<form action=“your_file.php” method=“GET”>
Employee Code : <input type="number" name="empl_kode"      placeholder="Employee Code" required="required"><br>
<button type="button" name="cek_empl" value="cek_empl">Check</button>     <br>
Employee Name :<input type="text" name="empl_name" value="<?php echo $name1xs; ?>"placeholder="Employee Name"><br>
</form>
.
.
.


//PHP code fragment on the other page

$empId=$_GET['empIdp'];
$result = mysql_query("select name from logindetails where       empId='$empId'");
while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $name1= $rowval['name'];
} 
.
.
.
.

$_SESSION['name1xs'] = $name1;
```

Comment: Not the correct answer. Read the question again carefully.